# Dúvida em Enviar SMS + Coordenadas GPS

Tags: java, android

Estou a tentar desenvolver uma *app*, onde necessito de obter as coordenadas GPS da localização do dispositivo para as enviar por SMS.

O que acontece é que eu pretendo que com um *click* num botão a lógica faça a aquisição das coordenadas e o envio da SMS com elas, com apenas um *click*.

O meu problema neste momento está em passar as coordenadas para o método `SendSMS()`.

Poderiam ajudar-me?

```
/*
    @autor: Nuno Santos
    @date: 27/06/2016
    @version: 1.0
*/


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Variable Declaration
    private AdView mAdView;
    //Permission Request
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 100;
    //GPS Location


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        /*Button PANIC Button
        @ Click this button to send a PANIC message to defined contact
        @ Inside the message go a PANIC message, name of person and GPS location
        */
        Button button_panic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_panic);
        button_panic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /*Alert If User GPS Location Not Enabled
                @
                @Comment: If GPS Location Not Enabled Show a dialog to enable GPS
                 */
                final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    //Runtime Permission Request
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {

                            } else {
                                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                            }
                        } else {
                            sendSMS();
                        }
                    } else {
                        sendSMS();
                    }
                } else {
                    showAlert();
                }
            }
        });

    }


    /*Send Message Method
    @
    @Comment: Method to send a SMS using an intent
    */
    private void sendSMS() {

        //SharedPreferences
        final SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
        //Define SharedPreferences
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("PANIC_PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //Get SharedPreferences to Send PANIC SMS
        //Retrieve SharedPreferences
        final String nome = sharedpreferences.getString("Key_nome", null);
        final String apelido = sharedpreferences.getString("Key_apelido", null);
        final String telefone = sharedpreferences.getString("Key_telefone", null);

        //Retrieve GPS coordinates


        String message = "PANIC - Preciso de Ajuda " + nome + " " + apelido;
        /// / + " " + "Esta é a minha localização: Latitude: + sms_latitude + " Longitude: " + sms_longitude;

        //Sens SMS
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(telefone, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Enviada.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    /*Request Permission
    @
    @Comment: Method to request permission to send SMS in Android versions over 23 - Marshmallow
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            sendSMS();

        } else {


        }
    }



    /*GPS Location
    @
    @Comment: Method to request permission to send SMS in Android versions over 23 - Marshmallow
     */
    private void showAlert() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Ative a Sua Localização")
                .setMessage("A Sua Localização GPS está 'Off'.\nPor favor Ative a sua localização para " +
                        "usar esta funcionalidade")
                .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }
}


O que eu não consigo fazer é após fazer a recolha das coordenadas no método seguinte: 

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String latitude = location.getLatitude()
        String longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
```

É enviar essas mesmas coordenadas para o método SendSMS para as incorporar na mensagem.

Alguma ajuda quanto a forma de resolver isto?

Answer (score 2):

Para que possa ter acesso aos valores das variáveis `latitude`e `logitude` em qualquer parte(método) da classe Activity tem de as declarar como campos.

Faça assim:

```
String latitude;
String longitude;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    latitude = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
    longitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
}
```

Os métodos `location.getLatitude()` e `location.getLongitude()` retornam um `double`, como necessita de usar os valores como *strings*, eles são convertidos recorrendo ao método `Double.toString()`.

A mensagem será construída assim:

```
//Retrieve GPS coordinates


String message = "PANIC - Preciso de Ajuda " + nome + " " + apelido
+ " " + "Esta é a minha localização: Latitude: " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude;

//Sens SMS
```